# Find values of DataFrame A in DataFrame B and replace them with other column's values (create unique identifier for panel study)

Tags: r, dataframe, uniqueidentifier

I want to find values from one DataFrame A in another 
DataFrame B and replace them with values from another column of B.

My problem in detail:
I have ten datasets that all together compose one-panel study. That means, that some people have been interviewed more than one time and - accordingly - have rows in more than one of those datasets. Each dataset also contains new study members who had not been interviewed before.

Unfortunately, the unique identifier to represent study members has to be deleted, for some reason. I have to replace it with another unique identifier without losing the panel quality (that is, the same person has to be associated with the same identifier in all datasets they appear in).

My idea was to:

a) load all datasets,

b) create a DataFrame with an allocation table with an old identifier and newly created identifier and then

c) "search and replace" identifiers in the original datasets.
The last step doesn't work.

**I have two questions:**

1) Does anyone know how to do step 3?
2) My way seems cumbersome. Does anyone know a more simple solution?

a) Loading

```
library(foreign)
#df1 <- read.spss("D1.sav", to.data.frame=TRUE, use.value.labels=FALSE)
#df2 <- read.spss("D2.sav", to.data.frame=TRUE, use.value.labels=FALSE)
#... (for all 10 datasets)
#For the sake of the example two random datasets that also 
#include some NA and "overlap"
df1 <- c(NA,NA,NA,seq(100,200))
df2 <- c(NA,NA,NA,seq(150,250))
```

b) Creating Allocation

(only for unique ids 
    because people who were interviewed more 
    than once should receive the same allocation 
    in all datasets (panel study))

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(df1,df2),
                 alloc=c(df1,df2))
df <- subset(df, !duplicated(df$id))
df$alloc <- 1:dim(df)[1]
```

c) Overwriting old identifer with a new one (doesn't work)

```
Here for the example datasets:
df1 <- ifelse(df1 %in% df[,1], df[,2], df1)
df2 <- ifelse(df2 %in% df[,1], df[,2], df2)
#With the real datasets in this form:
#df1$identifer <- ifelse(df1$identifer %in% df[,1], 
#df[,2], df1$identifer)
#df2$identifer <- ifelse(df2$identifer %in% df[,1], 
#df[,2], df2$identifer)
#... (for all 10 datasets)
```

Comment: I think the problem in the `ifelse` is the length of `df[,1]` and `df1` are not the same.  Also, the logical condition might be `.

Comment: Should be resolved easily with `merge`.

Comment: Thank you very much! @Khashaa - That is indeed an easy solution.